# Selecting large font and low vision css stylesheets at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I'm in the process of designing one of my first websites and I'm stuck on the following problem. I have 3 stylesheets: one for low vision; one for large font and the default one. I have 3 buttons to select these but I can only select one at a time. I was wondering if it's possible to select 2 at the same time ie low vision and large font or would i need to create a fourth stylesheet.

Here's what I have..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" title="default" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/large_font.css" title="large_font"     disabled />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/low_vision.css" title="low_vision" disabled />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/styleswitch.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.localscroll-min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
$.localScroll();
});
</script> 

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slimbox.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /> 
<script type="text/JavaScript" src="js/slimbox.js"></script> 

</head>

<body>

<div id="background">

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="accessibility">
            <ul id="access_list">
                <li><a href="#" onclick="setActiveStyleSheet('default'); return false;">Default</a> | </li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="setActiveStyleSheet('large_font'); return false;">Large Font</a> | </li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="setActiveStyleSheet('low_vision'); return false;">Low Vision</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <div id="header">
        <div id="site_title"><a href="#">Sean's Site</a></div>

    </div>
```

Comment: not getting what are you telling

Comment: sorry, I'm just trying to run 2 css stylesheets at the same time using javascript but i can't figure it out so i'm looking for any help if possible.

Comment: but when you add any css on one page then it will always run all the css. meanif you have 20 css on the page then also it will run all the css.

Comment: I know yes but i have it set up so that i can switch between separate stylesheets via javascript to cater for accessibility requirements for the visually impaired. I just want to be able to activate 2 at the same time. The accessibility div is where this is taking place!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want to selectively enable/disable each stylesheet instead of  selecting one of them as "the active one".

To do this, first give your stylesheets unique ids:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" id="default" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/large_font.css" id="large_font"     disabled />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/low_vision.css" id="low_vision" disabled />
```

Then create the javascript function `toggleStylesheet`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function toggleStylesheet(id) {
    var o = document.getElementById(id);
    if (o.hasAttribute('disabled') {
      o.removeAttribute('disabled');
    } else {
      o.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
  }
</script>
```

Now you can use that function in your interface:

```
<ul id="access_list">
  <li><a href="#" onclick="toggleStylesheet('default')">Default</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="toggleStylesheet('large_font')">Large Font</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" onclick="toggleStylesheet('low_vision')">Low Vision</a></li>
</ul>
```

Also see this Q&A for more information on the `toggleStylesheet` function: [HTML "link" (stylesheet) disabled attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564806/html-link-stylesheet-disabled-attribute)