# How to apply Custom theme for jquery dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I have 2 css files `jquery.ui.all.css` and  `jquery-ui.css(this is customized from jquery theme roller)`

I am using the `jquery-ui.css` for the `jsp` page & including it in header as link but for a dialog on the same page I want to change it to `jquery.ui.all.css` without affecting the styling of JSP, how can this be achieved?

Comment: Why not just apply the relevant styles to the dialog, no need for multiple and conditional stylesheets.

Comment: see post [HTML “link” (stylesheet) disabled attribute][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10564806/html-link-stylesheet-disabled-attribute

Answer (score 0):

It will only conflict if both css file has same classes with different styles. Just remove the css which is not necessary from jquery-ui.css file and use only which is valid for your dialog box.